# Red5 videochat freeze

Tags: flash, stream, red5

I've got a problem with videochat based on red5 server. Everything works fine, but if some people close browser instead of click "Stop chat" button, there is last frame from their stream. So it looks like freezing stream.
Is there an option to kill such stream?

Answer (score 0):

Option not, but you could implement in the Red5 application a method, for example implement the method:

```
/**
 * Notification that a broadcasting stream is closing.
*/
@Override
public void streamBroadcastClose(IBroadcastStream stream) {
  //Notify all clients
}
```

And then send a message via RTMP to all clients that the user has left, and then you can react in the client side UI and correctly remove/black that screen of the user that has left.

Sebastian

Comment: Actually, my client side is listening to NetStream events to remove video container. Is it the same thing? Because it works but not everytimes.

Comment: No, the method that I was posting is a Java method that you implement on the server side. You will then have to create RTMP message "XYZ" and on the client side listen on the NetConnetion (not NetStream) for the method "XYZ".